# Can't connect to mongolab.com

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When running `nodemon server` it logs `"Server running successfully on port 3000."` but it doesn't log whatever is in the `mongoose.connect` function. Not even an error.

### Config file

```
module.exports = {
    'database': 'mongodb://root:mypw@LINK-REMOVED/officr',
    'port': process.env.PORT || 3000,
    "secretKey": "key"
}
```

### Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var config = require ('./config.js')
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();

mongoose.connect(config.database, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to database.')
    }
});


app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
})

app.listen(config.port, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log('Server running successfully on port 3000.');
    }
})
```

Comment: There are several events of `mongoose.connection`, such as `error`, `open` and so on. Maybe you could find more information from them, [here](https://gist.github.com/richzw/3fe799f384a2037e963f) is one sample

Comment: @zangw, he skips the `on(error)` function but when he goes on the `on(connect)` function it throws an error when I debug. `throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event` it leads to `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000`

Comment: it seems that the connection is used by other process? or multiple instances of your node are running now?

Comment: Don't mind my comment above. I debugged when I was already using that port hence I got that error. However, when I close my app and debug again he goes into the `on(connected)` function and it logs 'server running on port..' but he never logs that it's connected to the database. After a while I get "lost connection with database".

Comment: `Lost connection with database` means the connection does not be built successfully. Maybe you can test this url with `mongod` in command line?

Comment: I just tried that and even that says it fails... `[thread1] Failed to connect to 54.161.96.170:39135 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
2016-01-07T16:02:08.499+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server`I don't get it.. I'm using the link form the website..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongolab was blocked by my Firewall at work, it works perfectly fine at home.